# Angularjs Material Design with JQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

**I am developing a new webapp and I want to use material design for it**.

Currently the backend is developed with laravel (php) and the frontend with **JQuery** and **materializecss**.
 The problem is that materializecss is not powerful enough for my needs (I need ajax calls, dynamic content...).
 Since i know angular has a FANTASTIC material design framework but i don't want to use angularjs, **i was wondering if i could use just the material design template** (even with some necessary angularjs code in order to run things) **and then develop my things with JQuery**.
 Would i be able to do ajax calls, update content dinamically, add visual elements of angularjs material design with JQuery?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yes you can use angular , http calls , with material . I am laravel and angularjs developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can use what ever you want 
even you can combine them and set jquery codes in angularJs controller although its not recommended cos you have what ever you want in jquery and angular both are awesome js frameworks .
if you are looking for material design you can use it without angularJs its a separate css and js framework .
[get material desing light](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i don't want to use it because it doesn't have material design animations and yet it doesn't have all the components that angularjs material design has. So if i got it right, i can use the material design framework of angular without actually using angular? Or should i still include their framework for the material design to work?

Comment: you can use angular material design by adding angularJs static codes that the angular design material needs and use jquery for you'r request , in case you can do ajax using angular sending and receiving data its so easy in angular that you may actually forget about ajax

Comment: I get your point and I would like to use angular too but I am really confused about versions of it and I don't want to use something that will be no more supported in a couple of years. Since jQuery is surely supported and powerful, I wanted to combine them

Comment: well it's you'r choice , i use angular 1.4 and i dont care if it's not supported